# How to append [string] [jquery object] [string] on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following

```
 var container = $(document.createElement('div'));
 var part1 = `<div  style="padding:5px" id="div${iCnt}"><input type='checkbox' onchange="checkboxOnChange(this,'${tmpId}')"/> `;
 var jqueryObj = tmpCp;
 var part2 =  `Log file ${iCnt}: <input type=text class="input" id="tb${iCnt}"> <input id="tbid${iCnt}" type="hidden" value="${tmpId}"/></div>`;

 $(container).append(part1);
 $(container).append(jqueryObj);
 $(container).append(part2);
```

What i want to archive is that the `<div>` at part1 warp everythings, however if i use append, it will automatically generate a close tag `</div>` after part1.
If i putting them all together, the jquery object will be parsing into string, display as [Object object] :/

Edited:

```
                    var tmpCp = $(document.createElement('div')).css({margin:'5px',width: '30px',height: '30px',background: 'url(./images/select.png) center'});
                    var cpId = tmpId+"_"+"CP";
                    tmpCp.attr('id',cpId);
                    tmpCp.ColorPicker({
                        color: '#0000ff',
                        onShow: function (colpkr) {
                            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                            return false;
                        },
                        onHide: function (colpkr) {
                            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                            return false;
                        },
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $(`#${cpId}`).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);        
                            $(`.${tmpId}`).css('background', '#' + hex);
                        }
                    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please give us an example for `tmpCp`. Also, container is already a jQuery Object, no need for the additional `$()` down the road

Comment: Updated the question, thanks for that tip! I though every javascript objects have to `$()` lol.

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand the question, you want to dynamically insert part1 + jqueryOBJ + part2 as html code into the container, is that right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know is this a ideal way to do it, but the following does what i want, hope someone can tell me a proper way to do it, lol.

The trick is that once the part1 and part2 HTML string is appended to the continer `DIV`,  i use the `:first-child` selector to get the first child and append the jqueryObject at the middle.

[image]

```
var part1 = `<div  style="padding:5px;display:flex;align-items:center;" id="div${iCnt}">    <input type='checkbox' onchange="checkboxOnChange(this,'${tmpId}')" checked/> `;                
var part2 =  `Log file ${iCnt}: <input type=text class="input" id="tb${iCnt}" > <input id="tbid${iCnt}" type="hidden" value="${tmpId}"/></div>`;
container.append(part1+part2);                          

$('#links').append(container);
var firstChild = $(`#div${iCnt} :first-child`);
tmpCp.insertAfter(firstChild);
```